# Python - Trying to randomly select an element from a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie to Python trying figure out how it all works. I'm trying to create a deck of cards and then randomly select a card (akin to dealing cards out), but I don't know how to select a single random element from a dataframe.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Hearts = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7","H8","H9","H10","HJ","HQ","HK","HA"]
Spades = ["S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10","SJ","SQ","SK","SA"] 
Diamonds = ["D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","DJ","DQ","DK","DA"]
Clubs = ["C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10","CJ","CQ","CK","CA"]

Deck = pd.DataFrame([Hearts,Spades,Diamonds,Clubs])
print(Deck)
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9  10  11  12  13
0  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  H10  HJ  HQ  HK  HA
1  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10  SJ  SQ  SK  SA
2  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  D10  DJ  DQ  DK  DA
3  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  CJ  CQ  CK  CA
```

I know there is a lot more involved but at this stage I would just like to be able to print one random element from the above dataframe. Hoping somebody will be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Create `Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for one random value use [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html), last select value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for scalar:

```
print(Deck.stack().sample(1).iat[0])
H9
```

Or use `np.random.choice` with flatten values by `np.ravel`:

```
print(np.random.choice(np.ravel(Deck), 1)[0])
H8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(choice(Deck)
'S2'
>> choice(choice(Deck))
'D1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will randomly select a row, and then a column.

```
Deck.sample(1, axis=0).sample(1, axis=1)
```